# redis zrank : Floating-Point Numbers May Lose Precision

Tags: redis, rank, sortedset

When I push score value length longer than 16 .
like 10000000000000000..
Then rank of sortedset get wrong .
How make it support 48 ?
or make it support string rank somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Scores are floating point values. These use the IEEE 754 standard and have finite precision. There is no way to increase the score's precision.